# Error reading config file. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, installation, config, database

I'm installing MongoDB by official tutorial, but I have an error in command prompt:

> **Error reading config file: No such file or directory**

This error happens when I try to start MongoDB with this command:

> mongod.exe --config C:\Program Files\mongodb\bin\mongo.cfg

Help pls!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try with the apostrophes `"`:

```
mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\mongodb\bin\mongo.cfg"
```

Probably its beacuse of space in phrase "Program Files"

Answer (score 6):

I realized that in my case the explorer was hidding the ".txt" extension. Once I deleted the .txt it worked perfectly. The same happened with the .cfg file

Answer (score 1):

Changing to double quotes fixed the issue for me. I was trying to install mongo on Windows Server 2016.

> mongod.exe --config 'C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.cfg'

VS

> mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.cfg"